# error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' while using OpenCV 4.2 with swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, opencv, uiimage, objective-c++

I have a function in `OpenCVWrraper.mm`:

```c
+ (NSArray *)findCentroids:(UIImage *)image;
```

In my `ViewController.swift`, I call this funcion as:

```swift
OpenCVWrapper.findCentroids(uiImage)
```

I'm sure that this `uiImage` does exist (cuz I can display it in `UIImageView`), it is not `nil`.

However, I get this error `error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'` while doing this in `findCentroids`:

```c
cv::Mat bgrMat, grayMat;
UIImageToMat(image, bgrMat);
cv::cvtColor(bgrMat, grayMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `bgrMat` is not properly set (i.e. empty). Inspect, if the Mat/image has been created/loaded correctly (typo in filename, access rights, ...).

Comment: I've find the reason, the `UIImageToMat` in `<opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>` does not give a correct conversion. I write a new one, it does work.